# Package Ruby to a standalone Mac OS X application?

Tags: ruby, macos

I know Python has [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#abstract). I was wondering if Ruby has anything like that. I know there is [OCRA](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2009/05/ocra-one-click-ruby-application-builder.html) (One-Click Ruby Application builder) for Windows, but what about for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus); it may do what you want.

From its homepage:

> Platypus is a developer tool for the
>   Mac OS X operating system. It can be
>   used to create native, flawlessly
>   integrated Mac OS X applications from
>   interpreted scripts such as shell
>   scripts or Perl and Python programs.
>   This is done by wrapping the script in
>   an application bundle directory
>   structure along with an executable
>   binary that runs the script.

**Edit** per [@XtraSimplicity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2737435/xtrasimplicity) in a comment: Platypus can't handle any input or output from `stdin` or `stdout`. That will rule it out in some cases.

Comment: I just used Platypus to turn a simple Ruby script into a full .app, so I could send it to someone else and have them run it easily, and it worked great!

Comment: Note that Platypus doesn't support interactive commands (i.e. no `stdin`, no `sudo`)

Answer (score 4):

MacRuby seems like the most likely candidate without knowing more details about what you're doing. It can make standalone native binaries.

http://www.macruby.org/ for more info.

Comment: Ditto. It would be the best option if you don't care about other platforms. However when mastering with Macruby, it is good to know how to work with xcode and interface builder.

Comment: Could I use it with QtRuby and send it to others without them having QtRuby?

Answer (score 1):

RubyCocoa includes a script (standaloneify.rb) to package all the Ruby files your project uses into the app wrapper, and MacRuby (recommended if you're targeting 10.5+) compiles to native code and thus it's no more work making a standalone app than with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to Windows, Ruby and Python are prebuilt for Mac OS X, so the easiest way might be using Cocoa with Ruby. You can get good information out of the book *[Programming Cocoa with Ruby](http://pragprog.com/press_releases/programming-cocoa-with-ruby)*.