# Howto upgrade Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9 on client computers

Tags: ruby, macos, upgrade, ruby-1.9

Of course I know howto install RVM and maintain multiple versions that way, and since I'm a developer I have all the requirements on my own macs (things like xcode etc). Everything is working fine on my own machines.

But how should I distribute my nifty scripts to other mac-users that only have the default 1.8.7 version installed?

I want them to upgrade to 1.9 but I can't expect them to run shell-scripts, rvm (with all its external requirements) etc to be able to run my short 30-line scripts?

Is there a shortcut/tool available so I can get them to upgrade to Ruby 1.9?

Comment: Maybe [boxen](http://boxen.github.com/) might help you with that

Answer (score 2):

Instead of forcing your users to upgrade Ruby, you could package your script into a standalone executable - see [SO question on packaging Ruby scripts into Mac OS X applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484432/package-ruby-to-a-standalone-mac-os-x-application)

Comment: This looked really promising as a concept! However I can't seem to pick anything else than Ruby 1.8.7 when building the project. But I will continue to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for automatically setting up development environments.

- Thoughtbot's [**laptop**](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop): *Laptop is a shell script that turns your Mac OS X laptop into an awesome development machine.*
- Github's [**boxen**](http://boxen.github.com/): *Automate the pain out of your development environment. Boxen installs your dependencies so you can focus on getting things done.*
- Pivotal Lab's [Workstation](https://github.com/pivotal/pivotal_workstation): *A cookbook of recipes for an OSX workstation.*

Thoughtbot's laptop focuses on getting a well-chosen standard set of tools to work on your Mac (you can see which ones in the script).

Boxen seems to be more for teams trying to build their own replicable custom development environment.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but I don't want to convert the users machines into developer toolboxes. They are happy with them as it is. All I want is to run a short script that requires Ruby 1.9 or above. I guess the path is either to create a fully contained App with a tool like platypus, or maybe go the MacRuby route. Installing the "proper" Ruby 1.9 simply has too many dependencies (XCode, Command Toóls etc).